# Spring - Mail sender within nginx

Tags: spring, email, spring-mvc, tomcat, nginx

In my spring mvc web application I am sending emails via org.springframework.mail.MailSender. It works good on localhost, although my application is deployed on tomcat with connection established through the nginx.

I think the problem is in nginx which may be blocking the 587 port.

The config of mailSender:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="myhost" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="info@myhost"/>
    <property name="password" value="mypsw"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">myhost</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My nginx confinguration:

```
upstream tomcat {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name mydomain;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-mydomain.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;`
.
.
.`
```

This is the error I'm getting when tryin to send the email:

[image]

The internet doesn't say much about this kind of configuration, so I'd be very pleased if you'd help me.

Comment: Provide the full config of `ssl-mydomain.conf`and also `ssl-params.conf`if you have modified it. From what I can see nginx is not configured to listen to port 587. My first intention would be your firewall, do you have checked it?

Comment: These config files have nothing to do with the case, I believe (correct me if I'm wrong). They are just for SSL config. 
If I just add the 
server {
        listen 587 default_server;
        listen [::]:587 default_server;
}
it still doesn't work, so how shall I configure it then?

Also, the nginx has full permission in my firewall.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to route an outgoing connection through nginx? I see at the moment no point in that.

Comment: @secustor How else can I make the nginx not blocking the 587 port? (If this is indeed the essence of the problem)

Comment: Nginx will only block a port if there is a `listen` block as it will then reserve this port, but I think you have to read some basics about ports, as the port you define in your bean is the one on the remote machine and not the one on the local machine. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket. This error basically says that you are not sending no HTTP response. Check if your application dumps because e.g of the changed HTTP headers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't related to anything like HTTP headers, as they are set dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found out the answer. The problem was that I am using the google cloud and it blocks the 587 port.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/